# How to get the top left coordinate of the image in canvas after translation?

Tags: javascript, canvas, transform, translate-animation

I have a question, how do you get the coordinate of the top left hand corner of the image after translating the image in the canvas? I want to make the image area selectable whilst leaving the white space unselectable, but without it, it is impossible to meet the condition of whether the mouse is within the range of the image or not.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var position = {
    start : {
        x : 0,
        y : 0
    },
    end : {
        x : 0,
        y : 0
    }
};
var imagePos = {
    x : 0,
    y : 0
};
var img = document.getElementById('img');
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var drag = false, selected = false;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);

function mouseDown(p) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveImg);
    position.start.x = p.pageX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    position.start.y = p.pageY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    drag = true;

    if (position.start.x >= imagePos.x && position.start.x <= (imagePos.x + img.width) && position.start.y >= imagePos.y && position.start.y <= (imagePos.y + img.height)) {
        selected = true;
    } else {
        selected = false;
    }
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveImg);
    selected = false;
}

function moveImg(p) {
    document.getElementById('mouse').innerHTML = 'MouseX: ' + parseInt(p.pageX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left) + '/ MouseY: ' + parseInt(p.pageY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);

    if (drag && selected) {
        position.end.x = p.pageX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        position.end.y = p.pageY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        var x = position.end.x - position.start.x;
        var y = position.end.y - position.start.y;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.translate(x, y);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx.restore();

        position.start.x = position.end.x;
        position.start.y = position.end.y;
        imagePos.x = position.end.x;
        imagePos.y = position.end.y;
    }
}
```

```css
h1 img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
canvas{
  width:inherit;
  background:white;
}
#info{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Image I'm using:  <img id='img' src="https://scontent-sin6-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.2081-6/c0.0.51.51/p50x50/10935987_911967968835908_1597235465_n.png?oh=01328f28a865b7cbe62cf67036b3615d&oe=5A5F490A">
</h1>
<div>
<canvas id='canvas' width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
</div>
<div id='info'>
<p id='mouse'>

</p>
<p id='image'>

</p>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sure you have a question if you post one :)

Comment: I did post one. The question is how do you get the coordinate of the top left hand corner of the image after translating the image in the canvas. I know how translation works but I don't know the formula to get the coordinates of the top left of the image after translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a formula, it is a simple change in your code:

Change

```
imagePos.x = position.end.x;
imagePos.y = position.end.y;
```

Into

```
imagePos.x += x;
imagePos.y += y;
```

Because you are translating the image by x and y, you also have to translate the position by x and y...